# How to navigate outside of components using react-router-dom and BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using BrowserRouter and i want to navigate outside of component. I can navigate using Router but can i do using BrowserRouter

```
 import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
 export const history = createBrowserHistory();

 <Router history = {history}>
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path="/"
                  component={Home}
                  exact={true} />
                <Route
                  path="/somePath"
                  component={SomeDisplay}
                  exact={true} />  
</Router>
```

And I can use it outside component as

```
import { history } from 'path/to/RouterConfigurations';

export const func1 = () => {

    history.push({
        pathname: "/somePath"
      });
}
```

Comment: In order to Route from Outside of components, you need to have access to the history object which Router component uses. since BrowserRouter doesn't give you access to the history object outside of component, you cannot navigate like this

Comment: use `withRouter` HOC to get access to the history: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter